# saving detailed data to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

In my simple app I have this data that the app generates:

```
 [{"cityName" : "Asm", "countyName" : "Sihel", "missingObjectType" : "Client", "appCode": "1"}]
```

I am hoping to have a report of missing object types aggregated against city and counties so a couple I would tell something like this in my reports:

```
  there are 50 missing clients in city Asm in appCode 1
  there are 22 missing clients in country Sihel in appCode 1
  there are 50 missing clients in appCode 1
```

How would I send such data to GA so I get reports that actually show actionable reports like the above?

Answer (score 0):

you might use [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) to pass your data to analytics however that won't be displayed in standard reports, you'll need to use [Custom Reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033013?hl=en) or API or [secondary dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6175970?hl=en).